# Regex is stripping out period at the end of sentence it should keep the period

Tags: javascript, regex

here is my regex: `alert(data.data.Message.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ' ') .replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')).trim();`

It is being used to strip out html tags.
[in this image you can see what the regex is returning. after the word 'placed' there should be a period and space but the regex is taking it out and is also adding a space at the beginning of the alert.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcVXp.png)
input: `<h2>Your request has been placed.<h2>you will be notified when it is available</h2>` after regex you are left with just the plain text since it removes the tags. but it is removing the period as well and seems to be replacing it with a space?

Comment: Please provide sample inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs.

Comment: the image I posted is the output

Comment: In order to maintain a high quality standard, questions on Stack Overflow are expected to have a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) contained within the body of the question, **not** in linked screenshots. This is especially important for [tag:javascript] questions, which can be run directly in the browser via Stack Overflow's Stack Snippets feature. (See also: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) In any case, you still haven't provided sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: this originally was the output: <h2>Your request has been placed<h2><p>we will......</b></p> the reg ex strips out all the html tags but is also stripping out the period after the first sentence

Comment: Please provide the **complete** (non-truncated) input and output **in the body of your question**, not in the comments. This makes all relevant information conveniently accessible by potential question-answerers and future visitors to the question.

Comment: okay edited it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in Chrome Latest (Windows 10). [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exvrboh9/)

Answer (score 0):

The text in your input example HTML is different than the output, and your input HTML is incorrect (2 opening h2 tags, one closing). I'd take a look at that first and verify that your inner text is correct because the regex looks fine.